# When splitting a folder with tens of thousands of documents into several folders, how can I handle broken links?

Tags: htaccess, links, directory, files, broken-links

I have over 30,000 html files stored in `www.example.com/docs`, and these files are linked to each other. When it comes to displaying the content of those files on my site, I use the following code: [HTML Include using Java](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

I learned today that my host allows a maximum of 10,000 files per folder. This means that I have start splitting up my files into different folders. I will probably create a number of folders like

- `www.example.com/docs1`
- `www.example.com/docs2`
- `www.example.com/docs3`

This causes an issue because I have to amend the hyperlinks within all 30,000 files, and I have to update the URLs within pages that display documents within those folder.

I don't mind creating the folders and moving the files, but I am really dreading updating the links and URLs. Is there a solution I can leverage? I am thinking something `.htaaccess` related, but I am not knowledgeable enough.

EDIT: my files are in the following format `doc[NUMBER].htm`, so it look like this:

- doc100.htm
- doc101.htm
- doc102.htm

Comment: What is the range/distribution of the _number_? It doesn't look zero padded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you do this would depend on how these files are named. You could, for instance, divide these HTML files into subdirectories according to their first letter (assuming a fairly even/normal distribution). For example:

```
/docs-a
    aardvark.html
    apple.html
/docs-b
    banana.html
    bee.html
:
/docs-z
    zebra.html
```

Then, given a request for `/docs/aardvark.html`, it needs to be internally rewritten to `/docs-a/aardvark.html` (since that is the true location). This is relatively trivial to do using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^docs/(([a-z]).*\.html)$ /docs-$2/$1 [L]
```

This assumes that all files start with a lowercase letter a-z and no one letter is excessively dominant (ie. well below the 10,000 limit).

Note that this is case-sensitive, `a` is different to `A`.

> EDIT: my files are in the following format `doc[NUMBER].htm`

In this case, @Stephen's suggestion in comments sounds good - base the directory name on the *last* digit (to ensure an even distribution) and use 10 subdirectories: `/docs-0` .. `/docs-9`.

```
RewriteRule ^docs/(doc.*([0-9])\.htm)$ /docs-$2/$1 [L]
```

> **UPDATE:** Can it modified to be `/docs/docs-0`

Yes, however, you'll also need to change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to be more restriction, to avoid a rewrite loop. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^docs/(doc\d*(\d)\.htm)$ /docs/docs-$2/$1 [L]
```

`\d` is a shorthand character class for digits. The same as `[0-9]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I have edited my original post to include the format of my documents. Is there anything can be done based on my format?

Comment: Base it on the last digit of the number instead:  `RewriteRule ^docs/(.*([0-9])\.html)$ /docs-$2/$1 [L]`.   You will need `docs-0` through `docs-9` directories.    I'd recommend the last digit rather than the first because for numbers the last digit is more evenly distributed.  The beginning digits have a preference for low digits, one being the most common.

Comment: Awesome. I will try this out and report back.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller That's a good idea! (I've updated my answer.) Although that does perhaps make the initial moving of files into the respective directories a little harder - perhaps write a script for that?

Comment: `mv docs/*0.htm docs/docs-0/` and nine other similar statements on the command line.   Less work than the 26 for each letter.  If you want a one liner to do them all: `for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do mkdir -p docs/docs-$i; mv docs/*$i.htm docs/docs-$i/; done`

Comment: Having a bit of trouble making this work. Do I need someone an tags around the htaccess code?

Comment: You need no additional “tags” around the directives. What happens? Any error? Do you have any other directives in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Got it! htaaccess expression had html expression, but my files are htm. I corrected and worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the help.

In regards to the one liner above to move files into respective directions, which application do I use to execute it. I am on a shared host.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but there is something I missed. Based on the proposed solution `/docs-0` folder must be under root folder. Can it modified to be `/docs/docs-0`

Comment: Yes, that's possible - I've updated my answer with respect to changing it to `/docs/docs-0/...`. @Stephen's "one liner to move files" is using the Linux (Bash) shell.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I tried running your one liner, but it doesn't create the folder or move them

Comment: I tested and updated the one liner.   I had `$` before the variable definition that was wrong.  I also changed it to created the `doc-0` directory within the `docs/` folder.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very. One slight correction wild card is in the wrong spot `*$i`, should be `$i*`