# Rewritting .htaccess file to direct to files using a wildcard

Tags: htaccess

Currently my html code points to

```
www.example.com/images/sub/ABCimage.jpg
www.example.com/images/sub/XYZimage.jpg
```

Due to a limit on number of files (9999) within the folder , I had to split images into different folders, and it looks like this:

```
/images/sub/ABC
     ABCimage.jpg
     ABCimage2.jpg
     ABCimage3.jpg

/images/sub/XYZ
     XYZimage.jpg
     XYZimage2.jpg
     XYZimage3.jpg
```

In other words, I have create folders based on first three letters of the image file. Can some help with writing an .htaccess expression to direct requests from 
`/images/sub/ABCimage.jpg` to `/images/sub/ABC/ABCimage.jpg` , but using the wildcard, so I don't have to write individual lines for each scenario.

Comment: Is `ABC` always uppercase? Can the case vary?

Comment: Always uppercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution uses very much the same principle as the code sample in the first part of [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/121112/1243) to your [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121110/when-splitting-a-folder-with-tens-of-thousands-of-documents-into-several-folders), just with a minor tweak to the pattern.

Using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteRule ^images/sub/(([A-Z]{3})[^/]*\.jpg)$ /images/sub/$2/$1 [L]
```

This assumes the first 3 letters are `A-Z` (all uppercase). The image basename is at least 3 characters long. All images are `.jpg`.

A rewrite loop is avoided by using the regex `[^/]*` (0 or more non-slash characters) so as not to match the newly rewritten subdirectory. A regex of `.*` here would result in the rewritten URL being matched and a rewrite loop would ensue. eg. `/images/sub/ABC/ABCimage.jpg` would get rewritten (again) to `/images/sub/ABC/ABC/ABCimage.jpg` etc.

Note that the above rewrites unconditionally. If there is any chance that `/images/sub/ABCimage.jpg` could exist then you will likely need an additional filesystem check (unless there is another pattern to these files). However, that is best avoided here since file system checks are relatively expensive.

> some images are in `A12` format, and therefore folders will be in the same format. Basically, first three characters could be a mix of letters and digits.

Modify the character class to include digits `0-9`:

```
RewriteRule ^images/sub/(([A-Z0-9]{3})[^/]*\.jpg)$ /images/sub/$2/$1 [L]
```

If the first character is always a letter, then you can be more specific if you wish and change the subpattern `([A-Z0-9]{3})` to `([A-Z][A-Z0-9]{2})`

Comment: Thanks MrWhite. Its similar to other question, but I was afraid it might get flagged as separate question, so I created a new thread. I will test out your solution and report back/

Comment: Yes, in that respect it is a different question.

Comment: Something I just realized that some images are in`A12` format, and therefore folders will be in the same format. Basically, first three characters could be a mix of letters and digits. How can I adjust it?

Comment: You just need to add `0-9` to the character class - I've updated my answer. Note that these are standard regex (specifically, PCRE - Pearl Compatible Regular Expressions) - the same as used by PHP and other languages - they are not specific to Apache.